# Solidity state var updated correctly in event log but truffle test fails - it's returning the old value?

Tags: javascript, testing, solidity, truffle

I've got a really simple contract I'm building and writing tests as I go. I'm wondering if this is a strange truffle js testing issue or... a user error? Here's what's up: Super simple contract that will hold persistent data onchain, stuff like contract addresses so I can access via interfaces. My dataHolder contract has a function to allow the admin account to set a mapping of a contract index to address. And... it works! I trigger an event that logs the new address being set in the mapping. The event shows it's successful. But when I query the chain's state var in a truffle test - it returns the old value. Maybe it's still not done - still holding onto a "promise" instead of reading the new value? Any ideas? Comments? Help!

Thanks!
cb

here's a snippet of the contract and the truffle test that fails:

```
contract IntelPropertyDataHolder {
    mapping(uint => address) public contractAddr;
    ...
    function setContract(uint _contractType, address _newAddress) public onlyAdmin isContract(_newAddress) {
        require(_contractType >=0  && _contractType <= 5, "Contract out of bounds");
        address prevContractAddr = contractAddr[_contractType];
        contractAddr[_contractType] = _newAddress;
        emit SetContract(_contractType, prevContractAddr, contractAddr[_contractType]);
    }
```

the event logs the operation as a success here:

```
    IntelPropertyDataHolder.SetContract(
      _contractType: 0 (type: uint256),
      _previousContract: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (type: address),
      _newContract: 0xE128cf0b22Eb1da88c88Dd4a790c98287d299439 (type: address)
    )
```

Yet this truffle test fails (all my other tests are working fine):

```
    it('Set a contract address', async () => {
        let nftAddr = await intelPropertyNFT.address;
        expect(intelPropertyDataHolder.setContract(0, nftAddr)).to.eventually.be.fulfilled; 
        let nftContractAddress = await intelPropertyDataHolder.contractAddr(0);
        await assert.equal(nftAddr, nftContractAddress);
    });
```

Truffle error reads:
1 failing

1. Contract: IntelPropertyDataHolder
   Set a contract address:

   AssertionError: expected '0xE128cf0b22Eb1da88c88Dd4a790c98287d299439' to equal '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'

   - expected - actual

Thanks for your help -
cb

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I'm still somewhat new to Solidity & truffle but have had issues with truffle's asynchronicity. I was able to create a test that worked by changing my truffle test to:

1. changes my
    `beforeEach(async () => { deploy contracts... }`
   to instead be
   `before(async () => { deploy contracts... }` I didn't even know that was a keyword (tho it certainly sounded plausible) & tried it on a whim.
2. then split the test above into two tests and put my other tests between them. This allowed the `expect(intelPropertyDataHolder.setContract(0, nftAddr)).to.eventually.be.fulfilled;` "promise" to atually be fulfilled before checking the value of contract(0) from the chain. This worked.